# Is it possible to connect Lua and javascript?

Tags: javascript, lua

I'm not sure if the question is well-posed as english is not my mother tongue. Is it possible to connect lua and javascript together? I did not find anything about that yet.

Or is it possible e.g. in a html-file to script with both languages like

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script></script>
    <?lsp 
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and maybe to share information between those languages?!

or ist it maybe possible to use lua in js or js in lua? like

```
<script><?lsp ?></script>
<?lsp 
<script></script>
?>
```

Comment: You could have a look at something like http://moonshinejs.org/ but not natively, no

Comment: Thank you :) gonna read me through that!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a few options for Lua usage on the front-end (**this is probably what you're aiming for as you'd like to connect/replace JS with Lua**):

- https://github.com/paulcuth/starlight
- https://github.com/gamesys/moonshine
- https://github.com/fengari-lua/fengari

There is some interesting WASM stuff in the works, like:

- https://github.com/vvanders/wasm_lua
- https://github.com/serprex/luwa
- https://github.com/fperrad/lua.wasm

For back-end there are even more options. Most noticeable are probably:

- https://github.com/leafo/lapis
- https://github.com/daurnimator/lua-http/
- https://github.com/sailorproject/sailor
- https://openresty.org/en/
- https://github.com/sumory/lor
- https://github.com/luvit/luvit

I've listed just a few. There is a lot.

Comment: thank you very much for all the work! I'm gonna read me through that! :)